# Unknown column 'cg.name' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, opencart, mysql-error-1054

I am using opencart, just got this error when trying to view customers in admin. I know nothing about SQL but I think it is telling me that I need to put cg.name somewhere.

> Full error:
>
> Notice: Error: Unknown column 'cg.name' in 'field list'
>
> Error No: 1054

```
SELECT *, 
    CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS name, 
    cg.name AS customer_group 
FROM oc_customer c 
LEFT JOIN oc_customer_group cg 
    ON (c.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id) 
ORDER BY name ASC 
LIMIT 0,100
```

> in /home4/pawpostc/public_html/system/database/mysql.php on line 49

Comment: does table `oc_customer_group` really contains `name`?

Comment: This means there is no `name` field in `oc_customer_group`. Try running `desc oc_customer_group;` in your mysql console to see the field you are looking for.

Comment: nope, no name field. any idea how to add it then?

Comment: What columns you have in `oc_customer_group`? I believe you would like to use one of them. just replace name in `cg.name` with that column name. Also make sure your use a right column in `order by clause`.

Comment: I have no idea how to use another column. there doesn't seem to be a cg.name, so no idea how to replace it. I also do not know what order by clause is... Anyway, if adding the name field to oc_customer_group can solve the issue, I would love to do that. Unfortunately I also don't know how to add it... any help on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the wrong version of a mod... deleted the mod, deleted the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The name of the customer group is in the table `customer_group_description` so you need to join that table onto it as well and use that

```
SELECT *, 
    CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS name, 
    cgd.name AS customer_group 
FROM oc_customer c 
LEFT JOIN oc_customer_group_description cgd 
    ON (c.customer_group_id = cgd.customer_group_id)
WHERE
    cgd.language_id = 1
ORDER BY name ASC 
LIMIT 0,100
```

Be sure to change the 1 for the language ID if it's incorrect

Answer (score 0):

File: admin/model/sale/customer.php

~line 76

Replace:

`$sql = "SELECT *, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS name, cg.name AS customer_group FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_group cg ON (c.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id)";`

with:

`$sql = "SELECT *, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS name, cg.name AS customer_group FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_group_description cg ON (c.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id)";`